# see api calling information on chrome developer tab

Tags: rest, api, web-services, google-chrome, http

i want to see calling of an API in chrome network tab to implement them in my web client.
i go to the domain [food.shahed.ac.ir](http://food.shahed.ac.ir)
then some api calls very fast and then redirects to another page very fast.
so i can not see the first requests .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check ***Preserve log*** checkbox.

Then all requests should be available.

Comment: Please don't add signatures to the end of your posts - they could be considered spam.